# Appending to a CSS Div in JQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a function which writes a description of a town.  I want to display that within a div.  But, when I try this it puts the text *after* the div, instead of inside it.

So it shows the div and the text, but not the text inside the div.  Below are the most relevant lines (skipping several irrelevant parts):

> `#description { height: 50px; background-color: #A7DBD8; }`
>
> `<div id="description"></div>`
>
> `function town () { document.write("You are in the town of
>   ",placevals[playerlocation][0],"<br>"); }`
>
> **`$("#description").appendTo(town());`**

I've tried using `.html` and replacing the div and that didn't work either.  (eg. `'<div id="blue"'>+town()+'</div>'`)

I'm probably just being dumb, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest reading through [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) and some JavaScript tutorials.

Comment: I took a couple of very long tutorials, and did consult documentation, but I guess I misread how this works or overlooked something.  I've been able to figure out my other problems, but this silly one was vexing me.  Maybe I need something more advanced than the Code Academy and Code School tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also be returning the text as a string, which can then be injected into the div element using the `.html()` function.

```
//Assuming these variables are defined.
var placevals = {}
    placevals['newyork'] = 'New York';
    playerlocation = 'newyork'

function town () { 
    return 'You are in the town of ' + placevals[playerlocation] + '.';
}

$("#description").html(town('newyork'));
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZynU9/4/

Comment: It looks like this is close to fixing it!  However, there are potentially hundreds of placesvals[playerlocation] entries.

Comment: I'll do some playing with it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Strangely, although this works in JSFiddle, when I repeat the exact same code it shows the div color but no text.  Weird!  May I have another issue.

Comment: I suggest looking in the console tab of your browser developer tools.  There is most likely an error being thrown which will help you determine the cause of why it's not displaying.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `town` function with no return value, and then you're passing the result of calling it (which will be `undefined`) into `appendTo` (which expects you to pass in a selector or element).

If your goal is to append the text generated by `town` to the `#description` `div`, then:

```
function town () {
    // Return the text, and use `+` to concatenate strings
    return "You are in the town of " + placevals[playerlocation][0] + "<br>";
}

// Use `append`
$("#description").append(town());
```

Comment: I think I see now what I did wrong - I presumed the output would be treated as a value - especially as it does output the text - just not in the div.

Sadly this suggestion isn't working for me though.

Answer (score 0):

[document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) is outputting the text into the document. Your function should probably return a value and then you can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which will properly interpret the `<br>` as well as the text you want.